# How to convert multiple object indexes into the nested array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that has multiple indexes and each index has different key and value data. Using the data below, how can I convert the data into the following array format?

```
"result": {
  "abc": {
    "0": {
      "1.0": 126,
      "0.9998": 3,
      "1.0003": 19
    },
    "1": {
      "1.0": 111,
      "0.9997": 4,
      "1.0003": 19
    },
    "2": {
      "1.0": 89,
      "1.0001": 75,
      "0.9998": 5
    }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "0": {
      "1.0": 1,
      "0.9998": 5,
      "1.0003": 20
    },
    "1": {
      "1.0": 141,
      "0.9997": 56,
      "1.0003": 19
    },
    "2": {
      "1.0": 89,
      "1.0001": 75,
      "0.9998": 5
    }
  }
}
```

The desired output that I am looking for is the following:

```
return [
  [126, 3, 19],
  [111, 4, 19],
  [89, 75, 5],
  [1, 5, 20],
  [141, 56, 19],
  [89, 75, 5]
]
```

I tried the following but it only returns the zero index in single array:

```
const values = Object.values(result)
const test = Object.values(...values);
console.log(test) 
// [126, 3, 19]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Done. I've updated the post with the code that I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "abc": {
    "0": { "1.0": 126, "0.9998": 3, "1.0003": 19 },
    "1": { "1.0": 111, "0.9997": 4, "1.0003": 19 },
    "2": { "1.0": 89, "1.0001": 75, "0.9998": 5 }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "0": { "1.0": 1, "0.9998": 5, "1.0003": 20 },
    "1": { "1.0": 141, "0.9997": 56, "1.0003": 19 },
    "2": { "1.0": 89, "1.0001": 75, "0.9998": 5 }
  }
};

const res = Object.values(data)
  .reduce((acc, item) => ([ ...acc, ...Object.values(item) ]), [])
  .map(Object.values);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks @Majed! That worked well. Another quick question, let's suppose if I have multiple objects inside data object and within each of those object I then have that key value pair structure, can I still get back the data in the same format?

Comment: @Shaun you're welcome. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Majed, just updated my post with the data

Comment: @Shaun is there a specific format for your data? or it can be both?

Comment: the data that I have contains multiple sub-categories objects and each of those sub-categories have key/value pair. The final result that I want needs to come in an array format such as `[ [...], [...], [...] ]`. Does that help?

Comment: So the depth is not necessarily 2? It can vary even inside the same subcategory? Perhaps you can provide an example of the extreme case you have and its expected output. Or does the provided example represent the general format of the data?

Comment: Yes the example that I provided represents the general format of the data that I have. You can see the actual data by visiting the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/35pb62dh/2/

Comment: @Shaun I updated the answer to result in the new expected output

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Majed. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values()`, then map with `Array.flatMap()` to get a flat array of the internal objects, and map again with `Array.map()` to get just the values:

```js
const data = {"abc":{"0":{"1.0":126,"0.9998":3,"1.0003":19},"1":{"1.0":111,"0.9997":4,"1.0003":19},"2":{"1.0":89,"1.0001":75,"0.9998":5}},"xyz":{"0":{"1.0":1,"0.9998":5,"1.0003":20},"1":{"1.0":141,"0.9997":56,"1.0003":19},"2":{"1.0":89,"1.0001":75,"0.9998":5}}};

const res = Object.values(data)
  .flatMap(Object.values)
  .map(Object.values);

console.log(res);
```